# How can I manually run a setTimeout timer immediately in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, settimeout

I have a form containing a `Repeater` which has a `RadioButtonList` and a `TextBox`. When a user changes the radio button or the text in one of the TextBoxes, the selected item and associated text for that Repeater item should get saved to the database.

Saving when a radio button changes is easy because of the `.change()` function, however for the `TextBox` I am creating a timer when the text changes that saves the data 2 seconds after the user stops typing

The problem is, if the user leaves the page or starts typing in a different TextBox before the timer executes, I need to manually execute the timer. How can I do that?

My javascript looks like this:

```
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 2000;  //time in ms, 2 second for example

$('textarea').on('input', function () {
    // Clear timer
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);

    // Set new timer to save form, passing current repeater item to Save method
    var parent = $(this).closest('.my-repeater-section');
    typingTimer = setTimeout(function () { saveForm(parent); }, doneTypingInterval);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timer is just a delayed function call. So, name your function and you'll be able to call it "manually:"

```
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 2000;  //time in ms, 2 second for example

$('textarea').on('input', function () {
    // Clear timer
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);

    // Set new timer to save form, passing current repeater item to Save method
    var parent = $(this).closest('.my-repeater-section');

    function callback() {
        saveForm(parent);
    }

    typingTimer = setTimeout(callback, doneTypingInterval);

    // call it manually like usual:
    // callback();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still figuring out javascript and didn't realize it was merely a delayed function call, not an actual object.

Answer (score 2):

Call your save function on blur, that way when the user leaves that textarea it will loose focus and if you listen to that event you can use your save function there

```
 $("textarea").blur(function(){
  //Call your save function here
});
```

Comment: Although this does provide me with a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do, I'm accepting the other answer since it answers the question I originally asked of how to run a setTimeout manually. +1 to this anyways though, as it's a better way of saving the changes :)